# Wrong behaviour of SQLite search

Tags: database, sqlite

I want to search for all values, which are bigger than 0.9. I can't show you the name of the attribute, because these are company internal names. But they are not necessary to show the current problem.

[image: search bigger than]

And this is the result:

[image]

My question: How is this possible? Is this the same reason as described in [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) ??

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 0.8 > 0.9;
0
SELECT '0.8' > 0.9;
1
```

You have strings in your database, and in SQLite's [sort order](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#sort_order), they are considered larger than any number.